# How does the Linux kernel remove a closed fd from the epoll interest list?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, polling, epoll

I am trying to play a bit with `epoll` and there is a part that confuses me a bit. So, from the man pages of epoll:

```
 6.  Will closing a file descriptor cause it to be removed from
           all epoll interest lists?

           Yes, but be aware of the following point.  A file descriptor
           is a reference to an open file description (see open(2)).
           Whenever a file descriptor is duplicated via dup(2), dup2(2),
           fcntl(2) F_DUPFD, or fork(2), a new file descriptor referring
           to the same open file description is created.  An open file
           description continues to exist until all file descriptors
           referring to it have been closed.

           A file descriptor is removed from an interest list only after
           all the file descriptors referring to the underlying open
           file description have been closed.
           ...
```

From my understanding, these examples are possible:

```
Example1:

fd1 added to the interest list
dup(fd1) -> fd2
close(fd1) - not removed from interest list because the underlying file is still open
event for the file -> epoll signals fd1

Example2:
fd1 added to the interest list
dup(fd1) -> fd2
close(fd1) - not removed from interest list because the underlying file is still open
another file open -> this gets fd1
event for the first file -> epoll signals fd1 (for me this looks like it should not happen)
```

My first question is if my understanding is correct.

The second part of my question refers to the way that Linux manages the silent delete from the epoll interest lists. So, when you call `close(fd)` and fd is in one or more interest lists of epoll, how does the kernel know in which interest lists that fd? Is this data stored in the underlying file structure? I guess my question is how does the silent removal of fds from the epoll interest lists happen step by step.

Comment: For the first part, the event data is whatever user space set it to and does not necessarily need to be interpreted as a file descriptor.

Comment: For the second part, the `struct file` is linked to a list of `struct epitem`s (defined in "fs/eventpoll.c") via `struct file`'s `f_ep` member and `struct epitem`'s `fllink` member. When the last reference to the `struct file` is closed, `eventpoll_release_file` is called (via `eventpoll_release`)  to remove (`ep_remove`) each `struct epitem` on the list from its containing interest list.

Comment: For the second part, you are correct. For the first part I am not sure I understand your answer.

Comment: For the first part I mean that when `epoll_wait()` fills in a `struct epoll_event` the `data` member (of type `epoll_data_t`) has the same value as set by the user code when it added the event to the interest list (by `epoll_ctl()` with `EPOLL_CTL_ADD` or `EPOLL_CTL_MOD`). The value of the `data` member needs to be something that the user code uses to identify the specific event, but it does not need to be a file descriptor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When fd1 is removed and same is dup to fd2 then kernel does not remove open file description but does remove entry from file descriptor table i.e internal data struct in kernel still remain intact but not associated with fd1 index anymore

Internally epoll fd keeps  interest list in kernel data structure where it understand what all open file description needs to be cleaned up when close for one of interest list is invoked. Following link does have more information.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195057/what-is-an-open-file-description